# Método __str__ es ignorado

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, clase, pycharm

Tengo un problema y es que utilizo el método `__str__(self)` en una clase para que cuando la imprima no me salga de esta forma `aeroport.Aeroport object at 0x00000237425DA588`, sin embargo cuando imprimo el diccionario me imprime de esta forma cuando debería salir los atributos de la clase.

defino la clase `Aeropuerto` (fichero 1) así:

```
 class Aeroport:
    def __init__(self, IATA, Nom, latitud, longitud, conecciones):
        self.IATA = IATA
        self.Nom = Nom
        self.latitud = latitud
        self.longitud = longitud
        self.Conecciones = conecciones

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.get_IATA())+' '+str(self.get_nom())+' Latitud:'+str(self.get_latitud())+' Longitud:'+str(self.get_longitud())+' Conecciones:'+str(self.Conecciones)
```

este es otro fichero (fichero2):

```
from aeroport import Aeroport


def cargar_dadas(fichero):
    try:
        file = open(fichero, 'r')
        dic_aeropueto={}
        for text in file:
            dic_conection = {}
            values = text.split(',')
            l_conection = values[-1].split()
            for clave in range(0,len(l_conection),2):
                dic_conection[l_conection[clave]]=l_conection[clave+1]
            values = values[:-1]
            aero = Aeroport(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], dic_conection)
            dic_aeropueto[aero.get_IATA()]=aero

        file.close()
        print(str(dic_aeropueto))

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Fichero inexistente')


cargar_dadas('Dades.txt')
```

> datos en fichero (.txt):
>   BCN,Barcelona,41.289182,2.0746423,MAD 00:55 CDG 01:25 OSL 03:02 ZRH 01:25 MLA 01:52 AGP 01:18 VIE 02:02
>   MAD,Madrid,40.472222,-3.560833,BCN 00:55 OSL 03:19 FRA 01:40 AMS 02:09 LIS 01:00 OPO 00:51 GLA 02:28 HEL 03:58

Comment: En lugar de (o además de) escribir la función `__str__(self)`, escribe una `__repr__(self)` pues cuando python tiene que mostrar elementos que están en otro contenedor usa `repr(objeto)` en vez de `str(objeto)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el [modelo de datos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) de Python tenemos a nuestra disposición dos métodos  para representar un objeto en forma de cadena:

### Método `__str__`

Retorna una una cadena que es la representación "informal" del objeto, es una representación "bonita" destinada al usuario final. Debe ser `lo más legible posible`.

Dicho método es llamado por el builtin `str()` y por `print()`. Si no se implementa `__str__` se llama directamente a `__repr__`.

### Método `__repr__`

Retorna una cadena que es la representación formal del objeto. Debería ser (si es posible) un argumento válido para `eval` de forma que este pueda reconstruir el objeto en base a la cadena.

Al contrario que en el caso se `__str__` lo principal es que **debe ser lo menos ambigua posible**, dejando totalmente claro la procedencia, tipo del objeto y composición. Es una salida destinada para el desarrollador, no para el usuario final.

Es llamada por `repr()`, durante la conversión de cadenas y **cuando el objeto es un item de un contenedor y se imprime el contenedor**. Obviamente es una representación menos amigable y si el objeto es complejo puede ser también bastante compleja en el intento de eliminar toda ambigüedad.

### ¿Por qué al imprimir un contenedor se llama al método `__repr__` de sus items?

Python intenta ser siempre lo menos ambiguo y más legible posible. con un ejemplo podemos ver muy claro esto:

Para `int` o `float` `__repr__` y `__str__` generan lo mismo:

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> repr(1)
'1'

>>> str(2.3)
'2.3'

>>> repr(2.3)
'2.3'
```

La razón es que no hay posibilidad de confusión en este caso, pero ¿qué pasa con `str` por ejemplo? Aquí ya cada una retorna algo distinto:

```
>>> str("Hola\tStackOverfow\n")
'Hola\tStackOverfow\n'

>>> repr("Hola\tStackOverfow\n")
"'Hola\\tStackOverfow\\n'"
```

Como vemos `__repr__` escapa las secuencias de escape y añade las comillas para dejar claro que es una cadena.

Esto es importante, imaginemos que tenemos una lista de cadenas y otra de enteros:

```
l1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

si se usa `__str__` al imprimir la lista de cadenas la salida sería:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

que es exactamente lo mismo que si imprimimos la de enteros... Por lo tanto, si vemos lo anterior ¿estamos ante una lista de enteros o de cadenas? ¿que hay de `eval`/`ast.literal_eval`?, ¿siempre construiría una lista de enteros...?

### ¿Cómo solucionas tu "problema"?

La opción obvia es implementar también `__repr__` (sobrescribir más bien ya que deriva de `object`) y hacer que retorne lo mismo que `__str__`, algo como:

```
class Aeroport:
    def __init__(self, IATA, Nom, latitud, longitud, conecciones):
        self.IATA = IATA
        self.Nom = Nom
        self.latitud = latitud
        self.longitud = longitud
        self.Conecciones = conecciones

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.get_IATA()} {self.get_nom()} "
            f"Latitud:{self.get_latitud()} "
            f"Longitud:{self.get_longitud()} "
            f"Conecciones:{self.Conecciones}"
            )

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Ahora bien, no es buena idea porque lo ya comentado. Siempre es buena idea implementar `__repr__` pero de forma adecuada para lo que está pensada:

```
def __repr__(self):
   return (f'{self.__class__.__name__}('
           f'{self.IATA!r}, {self.Nom!r}, {self.latitud!r}, '
           f'{self.longitud!r}, {self.Conecciones!r})')
```

Si quieres imprimir el diccionario, siempre puedes crear una función accesoria que te lo imprima como quieres:

```
def pprint_dict(diccionario):
    print("{", ",\n ".join(f"({str(item)})" for item in diccionario), "}", sep="")

pprint_dict(dic_aeropueto)
```

Por cierto, `print(str(dic_aeropueto))` es redundante, `print` ya  usa `__str__` como se ha comentado.

Comment: en la funcion de __repr(self) es necesario escribir "f'{self.__class__.__name__}('" ?

Comment: Podrías simplemente hacer `"Aeroport("`, lo de usar `self.__class.__name__` se debe a que si en un futuro cambiamos el nombre de la clase, no tenemos que modificar `__repr__`.

Comment: Se que no viene al tema, pero veo que me faltan conocimientos, me recomendarías algún libro de programacion ? donde me expliquen todo esto.