# Widget Entry de Tkinter no reconoce al presionar "Enter" utilizando el Bind

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy itentando generar un filtro mediante la utilización de `bind` para un widget `Entry` de Tkinter. El problema es que **no reconoce cuando presiono <kbd>Enter</kbd>**:

```
    #Input Paciente
    Label(self.pac_win, text= "Nombre: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.pac_win.busqpac=Entry(self.pac_win)
    self.pac_win.busqpac.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.pac_win.busqpac.insert(0,"Ingrese el Nombre: ")
    self.pac_win.busqpac.bind('<Return>', self.Busq_Pac())

#Cuando apreto Return en el Entry busqpac
def Busq_Pac(self):
    pacname=self.pac_win.busqpac.get()
    print("Obtuvo el valor "+ pacname)
    query_busqpac= "SELECT Paciente, Beneficio from Padron WHERE Paciente like '%" + str(pacname) + "%'" 
    self.get_pacientes(query_busqpac)
    Label(self.pac_win, text=query_busqpac).grid(row=2, column=0)
    print("hello")
    print(str(self.pac_win.busqpac.get()))
    print(query_busqpac)
```

Comment: Hola, añade siempre el código y los errores como texto, no como imagen. Las imagenes no indizan para búsquedas futuras, complican la legibilidad de la pregunta especialmente  en dispositivos móviles y  dificultan la reproducción del problema al no poder copiar y pegar el código. Por favor, edita la pregunta y copia el código como texto en ella.  Un saludo.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla gracias ya la formatee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

- **A `bind` le tienes que pasar una referencia al objeto callable** que se ha de ejecutar cuando el evento se produzca. En tu caso le pasas el retorno del método `Busq_Pac`, que es `None`, esto se debe a que lo llamas al colocar los dos paréntesis tras el nombre. Por lo tanto `bind` no recibe `Busq_Pac` sino `None`.

  Como el código es evaluado cuando se llama a `bind`, cuando ejecutas la app, el método se llama nada más ejecutar la app, por eso te aparecen los prints al iniciar.

  En vez de:

  ```
  self.pac_win.busqpac.bind('<Return>', self.Busq_Pac())
                                                     ^^
                                                     ^^
  ```

  debes hacer:

  ```
  self.pac_win.busqpac.bind('<Return>', self.Busq_Pac)
  ```
- Por otro lado, **`bind` pasa el evento que a causado su llamada al callable** como primer argumento. Tu método debe aceptarlo, lo use o no. Defínelo como:

  ```
  def Busq_Pac(self, event=None):
  ```

Una observación:

En Python no tienes que convertir a `str` algo antes de pasarlo a `print`, `print` llama por si misma al método [`__str__`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341719/15089) del objeto (que es lo que hace `str()`) y en caso de no estar disponible llama a `__repr__`. Por lo tanto, basta con que hagas `print(self.pac_win.busqpac.get())` y así con cualquier objeto. Es más, el método `get` de un `Entry` ya retorna un objeto `str` de todas formas.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Aún más por tu explicación y por compartir tu conocimiento. Estoy haciendo una inmersión en Python, vengo de años de otro lenguaje y otro paradigma. Saludos!