# Métodos __str__ y __repr__

Tags: python, poo

Necesito que alguien me eche una mano con lo siguiente:

Tengo la clase producto y la clase catálogo y necesito que el método `__str__` de la clase catalogo me llame al `__str__` de la clase producto y no se como hacerlo.

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, codigoproducto, descripcion, precio):
       self.codigoproducto = codigoproducto
       self.descripcion = descripcion
       self.precio = precio
    def __eq__(self, otro):
        if (not isinstance(otro, Product)):
            raise NotImplementedError("Incorrecto")
        return (self.codigoproducto == otro.codigoproducto)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.codigoproducto)
    def __repr__(self):
        return ""+self.codigoproducto+", \n"+self.descripcion+" \n"+str(self.precio)+""
    def __str__(self):
        return "Codigo Producto: "+self.codigoproducto+" \nDescripcion: "+self.descripcion+" \nPrecio: "+str(self.precio)+""
```

```
class Catalogue(object):
    def __init__(self, setProduct=set()):
        self.conjunto = setProduct
    def add_product(self, producto):
        if (producto in self.conjunto):
            raise CatalogueException("Producto existente en el catalogo")
        self.conjunto.add(producto)
    def __str__(self):
        return AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA
```

Esto es lo que debería devolver:

```
>>> new_catalogue = Catalogue()
>>> new_spanner = Product("S78", "Adjustable spanner", 35.99)
>>> new_hammer = Product("A45", 'Bush hammer', 15.5)
>>> new_catalogue.add_product( new_spanner )
>>> new_catalogue.add_product( new_hammer )
>>> print(new_catalogue)
Code: A45
Name: Bush hammer
Price: 15.5
Code: S78
Name: Adjustable spanner
Price: 35.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que iterar sobre cada item del atributo de instancia `conjunto`, llamar a su método `__str__`, mejor a través del builtin `str()` y concatenar las cadenas interponiendo un salto de línea entre cada una. Para esto último `str.join` viene perfecto:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(str(producto) for producto in self.conjunto)
```

Para `__repr__` sería similar, solo que usamos `obj.__repr__` o `repr(obj)` mejor.

Si no puedes usar `sr.join` puedes usar concatenado de cadenas, pero es feo y muy ineficiente, por ejemplo:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for producto in self.conjunto:
        string += str(producto) + "\n"
    return string[:-1]
```

Dos observaciones:

- En vez de concatenar cadenas usa formateo de cadenas, es más eficente y legible.
- En Python 3 no tienes que heredar de `object`, todas las clases derivan de `object` por defecto. Es una remanencia de Python 2.
- [`__repr__` debe retornar una cadena que represente de forma indudable el objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/341759/15089) y que por norma general , `eval` pueda usarla para reconstruir el objeto.

---

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, codigoproducto, descripcion, precio):
        self.codigoproducto = codigoproducto
        self.descripcion = descripcion
        self.precio = precio

    def __eq__(self, otro):
        if (not isinstance(otro, Product)):
            raise NotImplementedError("Incorrecto")
        return (self.codigoproducto == otro.codigoproducto)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.codigoproducto)

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"Product({self.codigoproducto}, "
                f"{self.descripcion}, {str(self.precio)})"
                )

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"Codigo Producto: {self.codigoproducto}\n"
                f"Descripcion: {self.descripcion}\n"
                f"Precio: {self.precio}"
                ) 


class Catalogue:
    def __init__(self, set_product=set()):
        self.conjunto = set_product

    def add_product(self, producto):
        if (producto in self.conjunto):
            raise CatalogueException("Producto existente en el catalogo")
        self.conjunto.add(producto)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(str(producto) for producto in self.conjunto)

    def __repr__(self):
        prods_repr = ', '.join(repr(producto) for producto in self.conjunto)
        return f"Catalogue({{{prods_repr}}})"
```

> ```
> >>> catalogue = Catalogue()
> >>> catalogue.add_product(Product("A45", "Bush hammer", 15.5))
> >>> catalogue.add_product(Product("S78", "Adjustable spanner", 35.9))
>
> >>> print(catalogue)
> Codigo Producto: S78
> Descripcion: Adjustable spanner
> Precio: 35.9
> Codigo Producto: A45
> Descripcion: Bush hammer
> Precio: 15.5
>
> >>> repr_cad = repr(catalogue)
> >>> catalogo_recons = eval(repr_cad)
> >>> catalogo_recons
> Catalogue({Product('A45', 'Bush hammer', 15.5), Product('S78', 'Adjustable spanner', 35.9)})
> ```

Comment: Habría otra forma de concatenar las cadenas sin usar join?

Comment: Hola @Miriam, he editado la respuesta contestando a tu duda, puedes usar concatenado de cadenas, pero es ineficiente. Un saludo.