# KeyError y NameError al ejecutar una función desde un String con globals() o exec()

Tags: python, string

Al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
class cliente(object):
  def __init__(self,cod,us)
    self.cod=cod
    self.us=0

def agregar(ide,code):
  globals()['clientes{}'.format(ide)] = cliente(code,0) #A veces crea el objeto, otras no

def suma(monto,ide):
  globals()['clientes{}'.format(ide)].us += monto      #opcion 1
  globals()['clientes{}.{}'.format(ide,us)] += monto    #opcion 2
  exec('clientes{}.{} += monto'.format(ide,us))         #opcion 3 ya le he colocado globals y locals
```

Con los globals sale el KeyError clientes1 y con el exec sale NameError clientes1

¿Qué hago?

La función agregar, pues crea objetos con el mismo nombre+ide, y pues dependiendo del ide, modifico las características de cierto objeto con la función suma.

Comment: Hola Jhon, podrías agregar un ejemplo de uso, llamadas reales a agregar y suma y las exepciones exactas que te producen para poder reproducir el problema? La **segunda opción y la tercera de suma no son correctas**, pero no debes tener problema con la primera. Por ejemplo, hacer `agregar(1, 45)` y **posteriormente** `suma(37, 1)` no debe tener ningún problema... Por cierto, ¿hay alguna razón para no usar un contenedor mutable, una clase contenedora o un namespace definidos a nivel global para contener los clientes en vez de agregar variables globales mediante globals() en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, en sí, lo que necesito hacer es una función que me cree distintos objetos que se identifiquen con una variable, ejemplo: client1, client2, ... clientn (n sería la variable), y que después según el valor de esa variable, pueda modificar el objeto adecuado de alguna manera mediante una función. 
Anoche probé con globals() para crear el objeto de otra manera, y solucioné parte del problema, ahora para modificar dicho objeto, no logro que surta algún cambio.

Comment: Ese tipo de problemas se suele resolver usando un diccionario, como  clave el nombre y como valor el objeto. Mucho más simple, legible y escalable. Las funciones solo tienen que agregar claves al diccionario y obtener el objeto mediante su clave, en este caso "client1", "client2", etc

Comment: Tendrías un pequeño ejemplo por favor?

Comment: Te refieres a que al momento de crear el objeto, se guarde en un diccionario utilizando como clave su nombre?
Y luego para modificar dicho objeto cómo haría?

Comment: Jhon he creado una respuesta, si es eso precisamente. En mi ejemplo he usado directamente el valor de `ide` como clave, pero puedes usar `f"cliente{ide}"` como hacías con las variables o lo que quieras, mientras sea hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La segunda y tercera opción de suma son incorrectas, la clave que debes usar para obtener el objeto del diccionario `global` es el nombre de la variable, en tu caso `clientes{n}`, como haces en la primera opción. La tercera no funciona porque  debe ser `clientes{}.us += monto`.

Ahora bien, Python es un lenguaje dinámico que permite éstas cosas, pero `globals`/`locals` están pensados más que nada para permitir la introspección, no para usarlo de forma masiva para generar variables en tiempo de ejecución. Es posible, pero el código termina siendo mucho menos legible y controlable.

Normalmente éste tipo de problemas se solventa mediante un contenedor, en concreto mediante un diccionario. En vez de crear variables, creamos parejas clave-valor, la clave será lo que ahora usas como nombre de variable, el valor será el objeto:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, cod, us=0):
        self.cod = cod
        self.us = us

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{'-' * 35} Cliente {'-' * 35}\n"
                f"COD: {self.cod}\nUS: {self.us}\n{'-' * 79}\n")


clientes = {}


def agregar(ide, code):
    clientes[ide] = Cliente(code)


def sumar(ide, monto):
    cliente = clientes.get(ide)
    if cliente is None:
        print("El cliente no existe")
    else:
        cliente.us += monto

def mostrar_cliente(ide):
    cliente = clientes.get(ide)
    if cliente is None:
        print("El cliente no existe")
    else:
        print(cliente)
```

> ```
> >>> agregar(1, 123)
> >>> agregar(2, 456)
>
> >>> sumar(4, 11)
> El cliente no existe
> >>> sumar(1, 13)
> >>> mostrar_cliente(1)
> ----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------
> COD: 123
> US: 13
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> >>> mostrar_cliente(2)
> ----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------
> COD: 456
> US: 0
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> >>> sumar(2, 23)
> >>> mostrar_cliente(2)
> ----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------
> COD: 456
> US: 23
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Ahora no estamos mezclando las variables globales con nuestros objetos Cliente, sabemos dónde están todos, de hecho podemos obtener todas las instancias iterando sobre el diccionario:

> ```
> >>> for cliente in clientes.values():
> ...     print(cliente)
>
> ----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------
> COD: 123
> US: 13
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------
> COD: 456
> US: 23
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> >>> for ide, cliente in clientes.items():
> ...     print(f"Cliente IDE: {ide}\nCliente COD: {cliente.cod}\nCliente US: {cliente.us}\n\n")
>
> Cliente IDE: 1
> Cliente COD: 123
> Cliente US: 13
>
>
> Cliente IDE: 2
> Cliente COD: 456
> Cliente US: 23
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la voy a implementar para ver que tal me va. Sólo tengo una pregunta, lo que retorna el método especial `__str__` de dónde lo sacas? o cómo lo construyes? (Lo digo por el 35 y el 79) Porque la clase en sí tiene varios elementos, no sólo dos como en el ejemplo.

Comment: `__str__` es el método "mágico" que llama `print` y `str` cuando imprimes un objeto de tu clase o lo conviertes en cadena. En mi caso lo uso para mostrar el valor de  los atributos self.cod y self.us. Lo de 35 y 79 no tiene nada que ver con los datos, son para genera las lineas de guiones que se muestran como separadores, me refiero a `----------------------------------- Cliente -----------------------------------` y a la linea de guiones final ("-" * 79). Si quieres implementarlo en tu caso, adaptalo para que genere la cadena que quieras y muestre los atributos que desees.

Comment: Es recomendable que también implementes `__repr__`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341719/m%c3%a9todo-str-es-ignorado/341759#341759

Comment: Muy bien, muchas gracias por tus respuestas y tu tiempo.