# Metodo __str__ en una clase en Python, para que sirve?

Tags: python, clase

Tengo este codigo

```
class Persona: 
   def __init(self, nombre, edad):
       self.nombre = nombre
       self.edad = edad 

   def __str__(self):
      return f'el nombre es: {self.nombre} y la edad: {self.edad}'
  
class Empleado(Persona):
     def __init__(self, nombre, edad, sueldo):
     super().__init__(nombre, edad)
         self.sueldo = sueldo
```

en otro archivo creo un objeto persona

```
p1 = Persona('Andrea', 34)
print(p1)
```

sin embargo si no pongo el  metodo **str** me devolvera una direccion a donde apunta el objeto creado

mi duda es para que sirve el metodo **str** agregado en la clase de Persona? actua como un metodo que solo muestra todos los atributos o metodos de la clase Padre o tiene otra funcionalidad?

Comment: Lee la documentación ahí si habla sobre estos métodos, llamados *dunder methods*. En este caso `__str__` funciona igual que cualquier otra función, recibe parámetros y devuelve un valor, que para ets casi si o si debe ser un string, puedes poner lo que sea en el método pero siempre debes retornar un string. Este método se invoca cuando la clase necesita ser convertida a string (equivalente a `str(p1)`)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Método \_\_str\_\_ es ignorado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341719/m%c3%a9todo-str-es-ignorado)

Comment: no seria igual solo hacer un metodo que retorne esos atirbutos? porque igual devuelve esos string @Christian

Comment: Si quieres puedes hacerlo, pero recuerda, los método mágicos son aquellos son utilizados internamente por python, si tu haces `a+b` python internamente está haciendo `a.__add__(b)` haciendo uso del método `__add__`, lo misma pasa con `print()` que invoca a `__str__` y `__repr__`. Si tu creas un método llamado `__mostrar_attr__` y haces `print(p1)` te seguirá mostrando la dirección de memoria, pues `__mostrar_attr__` no es un método mágico y python no lo utilizará nunca internamente.

Comment: okey esta bien lo tendre en cuenta! gracias @Christian

Comment: no tanto @PatricioMoracho porque queria saber la diferencia entre una y la otra