# Como pasar listas doblemente enlazadas a una cola circular e imprimirlas

Tags: python, array, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy pasando 3 listas enlazadas a una cola circular y a la hora de imprimirlo me aparece este texto en vez de la impresión
de las listas: [<Lista_Doble_Enlazada.ListaDoblementeEnlazada object at 0x0000019A15C346A0>, <Lista_Doble_Enlazada.ListaDoblementeEnlazada object at 0x0000019A15C346A0>, <Lista_Doble_Enlazada.ListaDoblementeEnlazada object at 0x0000019A15C346A0>]

```
from Cola_Circular import ColaCircular
from Lista_Doble_Enlazada import ListaDoblementeEnlazada
class Tarea_4:
    def __init__(self, lista1, lista2, lista3):
        colacircular=ColaCircular(3)
        listaD=ListaDoblementeEnlazada()
        
        for i in range(5):
            datos1 = lista1[i]
            listaD.AgregarInicio(datos1)
        colacircular.Encolar(listaD)
        listaD.ElDatosLista()
        
        for j in range(5):
            datos2 = lista2[i]
            listaD.AgregarInicio(datos2)
        colacircular.Encolar(listaD)
        listaD.ElDatosLista()
        
        for k in range(5):
            datos3 = lista3[i]
            listaD.AgregarInicio(datos3)
        colacircular.Encolar(listaD)
        listaD.ElDatosLista()
        
        colacircular.showEl()
        
def main():
    entrada1 = input()
    dividida1 = entrada1.split(" ")
    entrada2 = input()
    dividida2 = entrada2.split(" ")
    entrada3 = input()
    dividida3 = entrada3.split(" ")
    
    r=Tarea_4(dividida1, dividida2, dividida3)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Esta son las clases que use:

```
class ColaCircular:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.max=t #número máximo de elementos de la cola
        self.colacirc=[] #se inicializa la lista
        self.n=0 #número de elementos actuales en la cola circular
        self.frente=0 #posición de incio de la cola
        for i in range (self.max): #se asigna None en los valores de la cola
            self.colacirc.append(None)
            
    def Encolar(self,dato):
        if self.n!=self.max: #si la cola no se ha llenado entonces se procede a agregar elementos
            self.pos=(self.frente+self.n)%self.max #se calcula la posicion del dato a ingresar
            self.colacirc[self.pos]=dato #se agrega el dato a la cola circular
            self.n=self.n+1 #se incrementa el número de elementos en la cola
            print("frente: ",self.frente," n ", self.n,"maximo: ",self.max," pos: ", self.pos)
        else:
            print("Cola circular llena")
            
    def Desencolar(self): 
        if not self.estaVacia(): #si la cola circular no está vacía, entonces:
            salida=self.colacirc[self.frente] #se obtiene el elemento de la posición de frente
            self.colacirc[self.frente]=None #el elemento ahora es None
            self.n=self.n-1 #se decrementa el número de elementos en la cola
            self.frente=(self.frente+1)%self.max #se calcula la nueva posición de frente
            #print("frente: ",self.frente, "n: ",self.n)
            return salida #se retorna el valor
        print("La cola circular esta vacia")
        return None

    def estaVacia(self):
        #print(self.n)
        return self.n==0
    
    def showEl(self):
        print(self.colacirc)
        
    def vaciar(self):
        for i in range (self.max):
            self.colacirc[i]=None
        self.n=0
        
    def primero(self):
        if not self.estaVacia():
            return self.colacirc[self.frente]
        print("La cola circular esta vacia")
        return None
    
    def ultimo(self):
        if not self.estaVacia():
            return self.colacirc[self.pos]
        print("La cola circular esta vacia")
        return None    
    
    def tamanio(self):
        return (self.frente+self.n)-1
```

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, dato):
        self.dato=dato
        self.siguiente=None
        self.anterior=None
    def GetDato(self):
        return self.dato
    def GetSiguiente(self):
        return self.siguiente
    def SetDato(self,nuevoDato):
        self.dato=nuevoDato
    def SetSiguiente(self,nuevoSig):
        self.siguiente=nuevoSig
    def GetAnterior(self):
        return self.anterior
    def SetAnterior(self,nuevoAnt):
        self.anterior=nuevoAnt
class ListaDoblementeEnlazada:
    def __init__(self):
        self.primero=None
        self.ultimo=None
        self.t=0
    def EstaVacia(self):
        return self.primero==None
    def AgregarUltimo(self,dato):
        if self.EstaVacia():
            self.ultimo=Nodo(dato)
            self.primero=self.ultimo
        else:
            aux=self.ultimo
            nnodo=Nodo(dato)
            aux.SetSiguiente(nnodo)
            self.ultimo=nnodo
            self.ultimo.SetAnterior(aux)
        self.t+=1
    def AgregarInicio(self,dato):
        if self.EstaVacia():
            self.ultimo=Nodo(dato)
            self.primero=self.ultimo
        else:
            aux=Nodo(dato)
            aux.SetSiguiente(self.primero)
            self.primero.SetAnterior(aux)
            self.primero=aux
        self.t+=1

    def RecorrerInicio(self):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            nodo=self.primero
            datos="["
            while nodo!=None:
                if(nodo.GetSiguiente()!=None):
                    datos=datos+str(nodo.GetDato())+","
                    nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                else:
                    datos=datos+str(nodo.GetDato())+"]"
                    nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
            print(datos)
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")
    def RecorrerFinal(self):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            nodo=self.ultimo
            datos="["
            while nodo!=None:
                if(nodo.GetAnterior()!=None):
                    datos=datos+str(nodo.GetDato())+","
                    nodo=nodo.GetAnterior()
                else:
                    datos=datos+str(nodo.GetDato())+"]"
                    nodo=nodo.GetAnterior()
            print(datos)
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")
    def Tamanio(self):
        return self.t
    def EliminarNodo(self,pos):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            if (pos <self.t) & (pos>=0):
                nodo=self.primero
                c=0
                if(pos==c):  
                    self.primero=self.primero.GetSiguiente()
                else:
                    while (nodo!=None) & (c<pos):
                        aux=nodo
                        nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                        c+=1
                    aux.SetSiguiente(nodo.GetSiguiente())
                self.t=self.t-1
            else:
                print("Fuera de los índices de la lista")
            if self.t==0:
                self.primero=None
                self.ultimo=None
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")
    def Eliminar(self,dato):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            nodo=self.primero
            anterior=None
            encontrado=False
            while not encontrado and nodo!=None:
                if(nodo.GetDato()==dato):
                    encontrado=True
                else:
                    anterior=nodo
                    nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
            if not encontrado:
                print("No se encontro")
            else:
                if anterior==None:
                    self.primero=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                else:
                    anterior.SetSiguiente(nodo.GetSiguiente())
                self.t=self.t-1
            if self.t==0:
                self.primero=None
                self.ultimo=None
        else:
            print("lista vacia")
    def ElDatosLista(self):
        self.primero=None
        self.ultimo=None
        self.t=0
    def Insertar(self, pos,dato):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
        
            if pos==0:

                aux=Nodo(dato)
                aux.SetSiguiente(self.primero)
                self.primero.SetAnterior(aux)
                self.primero=aux
                self.t=self.t+1
            else:
                nodo=self.primero
                if(pos <self.t) & (pos>=0):
                    c=0
                    while (nodo!=None) & (c<pos):
                        aux=nodo
                        nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                        c+=1
                    nnodo=Nodo(dato)
                    aux.SetSiguiente(nnodo)
                    nnodo.SetAnterior(aux)
                    nnodo.SetSiguiente(nodo)
                    nodo.SetAnterior(nnodo)
                    self.t=self.t+1
                else:
                    print("Fuera de los índices de la lista")
            
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")

    def SetNodo(self,pos,dato):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            nodo=self.primero
            if(pos <self.t) & (pos>=0):
                c=0
                while (nodo!=None) & (c<=pos):
                    aux=nodo
                    nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                    c+=1
                aux.SetDato(dato)
            else:
                print("Fuera de los índices de la lista")
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")
    def GetNodo(self,pos):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            nodo=self.primero
            if (pos <self.t) & (pos>=0):
                c=0
                while (nodo!=None) & (c<=pos):
                    aux=nodo
                    nodo=nodo.GetSiguiente()
                    c+=1
                return aux.GetDato()
            else:
                print("Fuera de los índices de la lista")
        else:
            print("Lista vacia")
            return None
    def GetPrimero(self):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            return self.primero.GetDato()
        print("Lista Vacia")
        return None
    def GetUiltimo(self):
        if not self.EstaVacia():
            return self.ultimo.GetDato()
        print("Lista Vacia")
        return None
```

En el programa el usuario tiene que agregar 5 variables de tipo String y estos deben de ser agregados a una lista doblemente enlazada y esta lista tiene que ser agregada a una cola circular, esto se debe de repetir 3 veces por lo que al final la cola circular debe de contener 3 listas doblemente enlazadas con 5 valores cada una, lo que hice fue pedir los datos y agregarlos a la lista doblemente enlazada para después enviar la lista directamente a la cola circular, luego de confirmar que la lista doblemente enlazada este vacía repeti el proceso con las otras 2 listas con elementos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `showEl` simplemente imprime `self.colacirc`, que es un contenedor, una lista. Python en estos casos llama al método `__repr__` de las instancias contenidas en la lista, que es el que retorna lo de `<Lista_Doble_Enlazada.ListaDoblementeEnlazada object at ...>`. Puedes mirarte esta otra pregunta para entender por que:

[Método **str** es ignorado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341719/m%C3%A9todo-str-es-ignorado)

Si quieres que tus clases al ser imprimidas muestren una salida personalizada, implementa el método [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) en ellas. Este método debe retornar una cadena (`str`) y es llamado por `print()`, `format()` y `str()`.

Dado que no mencionas detalladamente como quieres la salida, te dejo un ejemplo simplificado con dos clases:

```
class Caja:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont = []
        
    def guardar(self, objeto):
        self.cont.append(objeto)
        
    def __str__(self):
        objs = "#\n#".join(f'{str(objeto): ^{40}}' for objeto in self.cont)
        return f'{"#" * 42}\n#{objs}#\n{"#" * 42}'
        
    
class Objeto:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Un objeto {self.nombre}"
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    caja = Caja()
    caja.guardar(Objeto("tijeras"))
    caja.guardar(Objeto("taza"))
    print(caja)
```

Lo que mostrara:

```
##########################################
#           Un objeto tijeras            #
#             Un objeto taza             #
##########################################
```

Dos pequeños apuntes ajenos al problema:

- Te recomiendo que te mires [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) sobre las convenciones de estilo en Python. Nada te obliga a seguirlas, pero hacen el código mas legible para otros desarrolladores. Por ejemplo, para los métodos de instancia se usa snake_case en vez de PascalCase (reservado para nombre de las clases).
- Para saber si un objeto es o no `None` (que es un singleton), la forma correcta generalmente es usar el operador `is`, es decir `if x is None` e `if x is not None` en vez de `if x == None` e `if x != None`. Hay varias razones, la primera es que es considerablemente mas eficiente, otra razón es que usando operadores de comparación te puedes encontrar con clases que retorna `True` cuando no es cierto (por como implementan el método `__eq__`) y también hay razones de legibilidad.